# downloading and working with sakela database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I downloaded the sakela database in mysql..But i couldnt able to work with it from my sql workbench..i get the following error:

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\aravind\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphk53klkf.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\Users\aravind\Downloads\sakila-db (1)\sakila-data.sql"
ERROR 1049 (42000) at line 38: Unknown database 'sakila'

Operation failed with exitcode 1

10:49:11 Import of C:\Users\aravind\Downloads\sakila-db (1)\sakila-data.sql has finished with 1 errors

Answer (score 0):

Create the database first:

```
mysql.exe --defaults-file="C:\Users\aravind\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphk53klkf.cnf" --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8  -e 'create database sakila'
```